# Multi-Table Groupwise Max Problem where I need a second field along with the max

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a query I'm having trouble with that involves 3 tables described below. There are more fields that are immaterial to this query.

```
users:
  id
  display_name
matches:
  id
  league_seasons_id
  date_played
  winner_id
  loser_id
players:
  id
  match_id
  player_id
  nth_match
  division
  result   # values are "Win" or "Loss"
  end_hcp
```

I'm trying to produce output like this:

```
  Name        Hcp   Wins   Losses   High Run    HR Pct of Hcp
  Alan        705    12       2       27            3.83%
  Bill        815    10       4       30            3.68%
  Charlie     611     9       5       12            1.96%
  Denise      788     8       6       15            1.90%
  ...
```

The query below mostly works, except for the `Hcp` column. In the players table there are 2 records for each match, one with the winner's info and one with the loser's. In each record is the `start_hcp` and the `end_hcp`, i.e. the handicap that player had before playing the match and the new one based on the match.

I need the `end_hcp` from the very last match that each player played up until now (the date/time of the query). I'm guessing there's going to be a subquery involved but I haven't figured out what it is.

```
SELECT 
    p.division AS Division,
    u.display_name AS Name,
    p.end_hcp AS Handicap,
    count(if(result = "Win", 1, NULL)) AS Wins,
    count(if(result = "Loss", 1, NULL)) AS Losses,
    max(high_run) AS "High Run",
    concat(truncate((max(high_run) * 100 / p.end_hcp), 2), '%') AS "HR Pct of Hcp"
FROM 
    `lwljhb_lwl_players` AS p,
    `lwljhb_lwl_matches` AS m,
    `lwljhb_users` AS u
WHERE 
    m.league_seasons_id = 9 AND
    p.match_id = m.id AND
    p.player_id = u.id AND
    u.display_name <> "Bye"
GROUP BY u.display_name
ORDER BY p.division, Wins DESC, Losses
```

Comment: Thanks ypercube for the edits, I posted in a hurry before I ran out to get my great-grandkids from school.

Comment: Sounds like a "groupwise max" problem.  See the tag I added.

Comment: @Rick James Thanks for the reference to Groupwise max that does seem to be the type of problem I have and explains why my first attempts to solve it have been unsuccessful. The resolutions I have found, however, all refer to one table and my data is spread over two. I've found it very difficult to make this work. Can you assist further?

Comment: A possibility:  Define a `VIEW` with your 2-table query, then use that view name in the place where you would have the table for doing the groupwise-max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a couple comments from @Rick James above I was able to find information on the Groupwise Max problem. Though no solution I found directly solved my issue of needing a second field from the record containing the max(nth_match) I was able to use the technique of making temp tables to get the data I needed and then joining them to my data tables to get my answer.

Here's the code if anyone's interested. Also, If someone sees a better way than making two temp tables I'd love to see it, I must have tried 20 different non-working ideas before this one.

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp1;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp1
SELECT player_id,
       max(nth_match) AS last_match
FROM `lwljhb_lwl_players` AS p INNER JOIN `lwljhb_lwl_matches` AS m
ON    p.match_id = m.id
WHERE m.playoff_round = 0 AND
      m.league_seasons_id = 9
GROUP BY p.player_id;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp2;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp2
SELECT p.player_id,
       t1.last_match,
       p.end_hcp
FROM `temp1` AS t1 INNER JOIN `lwljhb_lwl_players` AS p
ON t1.last_match = p.nth_match AND t1.player_id = p.player_id
GROUP BY p.player_id;

SELECT p.division AS Division,
       u.display_name AS Name,
       t2.end_hcp AS Handicap,
       count(if(result = "Win", 1, NULL)) AS Wins,
       count(if(result = "Loss", 1, NULL)) AS Losses,
       max(high_run) AS "High Run",
       concat(truncate((max(high_run) * 100 / t2.end_hcp), 2), '%') AS "HR Pct of Hcp"
FROM `lwljhb_lwl_players` AS p
INNER JOIN `lwljhb_users` AS u
INNER JOIN `lwljhb_lwl_matches` AS m
INNER JOIN `temp2` AS t2
ON p.match_id = m.id AND
   p.player_id = u.id AND
   t2.player_id = p.player_id
WHERE u.display_name <> "Bye" AND
      m.league_seasons_id = 9 AND
      p.division = "A" AND
      m.playoff_round = 0
GROUP BY u.display_name
ORDER BY Wins DESC, Losses, t2.end_hcp DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a MySQL guy but what about something like the following (for end_hcp)?

**Edit: based on syntax comment**

```
SELECT 
    p.division AS Division,
    u.display_name AS Name,
    (select max(end_hcp) from lwljhb_lwl_players where player_id = p.player_id and match_id =(select max(p.match_id) from lwljhb_lwl_players where p.player_id = u.id))
 AS Handicap,
    count(if(result = "Win", 1, NULL)) AS Wins,
    count(if(result = "", 1, NULL)) AS Losses,
    max(high_run) AS "High Run",
    concat(truncate((max(high_run) * 100 / p.end_hcp), 2), '%') AS "HR Pct of Hcp"
FROM 
    `lwljhb_lwl_players` AS p,
    `lwljhb_lwl_matches` AS m,
    `lwljhb_users` AS u
WHERE 
    m.league_seasons_id = 9 AND
    p.match_id = m.id AND
    p.player_id = u.id AND
    u.display_name <> "Bye"
GROUP BY u.display_name
ORDER BY p.division, Wins DESC, Losses
```

Comment: I inserted your line in place of "p.end_hcp AS Handicap" but got a MySQL syntax error. Not sure if that'is what you were saying to do. I think you inserted your subquery in the wrong place.

Comment: OK, found a MySQL syntax checker. See if this gets you closer to your goal--so to speak...

Comment: Error: subroutine returns more than one row

Comment: I was afraid that was going to happen without me being able to see the data. Without providing the Limit 1 hack, try my next edit--above. I added player_id = p.player_id in one more additional place in the subquery.

Comment: Still getting the same error: subroutine returns more than one row. You edited my code, right, not just the one line showing the change below the code? Also, end_hcp appears twice in the query, nd you only replaced one of them. Is that right?

Comment: I did edit. I see the end_hcp at the top is probably the one you want to change. I rearranged that part, but we're still going to get the "more than one row" error--same code/different place. It would help to see the actual data... I put max(end_hcp) in there but, without the data I'm guessing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67120/discussion-between-john-biddle-and-sting).